# Joining two tables and selecting rows not present in the second 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a table called users with a user called Bob like this:

```
username
  Bob
```

I have another table called mail with the following rows:

```
sender | receiver
Marley | Bob
 Saget | Bob
```

I have another table called block with the following rows:

```
blocker | blocked
 Marley | Bob
```

I want to select users from the table user and the number of messages they received BUT ignore messages from blocked users. So the result should be like this:

```
users.username | count_mail 
 Bob           |  1
```

So as you can see I need to get Bob along with the number of messages he received which is only 1 since Bob blocked Marley so the message by Saget should be the only 1 counted.

I use the following query but it returns nothing:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(mail) AS count_mail FROM users 
LEFT JOIN block ON (block.blocker = users.username) 
LEFT JOIN mail ON (mail.receiver = users.username 
                   AND mail.sender <> block.blocked)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.username, COUNT(mail.receiver) AS count_mail
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN mail ON mail.receiver = users.username 
LEFT JOIN block ON block.blocker = users.username
    AND mail.sender = block.blocked
WHERE block.blocked IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

This works because it only gets hits when the left join to blocker fails - asserted by the where clause tasting for a non-join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT user, COUNT(mail) AS count_mail FROM users 
LEFT JOIN mail ON (mail.receiver = users.username)
WHERE (mail.sender is null 
         or NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1 FROM block 
              WHERE mail.sender = block.blocker
              AND mail.receiver = block.blocked)
      )
```

OR

```
SELECT user, COUNT(mail) AS count_mail FROM users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM mail WHERE NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1 FROM block 
                   WHERE mail.sender = block.blocker
                   AND mail.receiver = block.blocked)
          ) mail ON (mail.receiver = users.username)
```